# How to use tf.keras.layers.Normalization for more than one feature inside the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

This [reproducible example](https://github.com/JN37/ML_Models/blob/dde00df5bb29f12fdfc3c5e61d517378f83ebd15/Supervised%20models/Linear%20Regression.py) creates a basic regression model predicting MPG given Horsepower (hope I am OK to just provide link). As far as I understand, this bakes the transformation of the feature Horsepower into the model's training - also refered to as ["inside the model"](https://keras.io/guides/preprocessing_layers/). This is appealing as the model does the necessary transformation of raw data during scoring/inference e.g. after deployment (please correct me if I misunderstood). I am wondering, how this could be implemented when one has more than on independent variable. This is taken from the reproducible code quoted above:

```
horsepower_normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(input_shape=[1, ], axis=None)
horsepower_normalizer.adapt(horsepower)

horsepower_normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(input_shape=[1, ], axis=None)
horsepower_normalizer.adapt(horsepower)

horsepower_model = Sequential([
    horsepower_normalizer,
    layers.Dense(units=1)
])
```

So let us say we have a list of numeric features `X, Y, Z` could the model definition code be produced based on this (e.g. via the functional API)? Any pointers would be very much welcome. Thanks!

PS:

I am currently trying to learn Keras + TF and ideally I want the normalisation make part of the mode/training. I use very rudemnetary code (to be improved!) along those lines:

```
train_data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
val_data = pd.read_csv('val.csv')

target_name = 'ze_target'

y_train = train_data[target_name]
X_train = train_data.drop(target_name, axis=1)

y_val = train_data[target_name]
X_val = train_data.drop(target_name, axis=1)

def create_model():
    
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=X.shape[1], activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=X.shape[1], activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(20, input_dim=X.shape[1], activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), loss = 'mse')
    return model

model = create_model()
model.summary()

model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_val,y_val), batch_size=128, epochs=30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tf.concat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) and concatenate three features on axis=1 then use [`tf.keras.layers.Normalization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Normalization) for three feature like below, because we want to normalize on three features, make sure to set `input_shape=(3,)` and `axis=-1`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.uniform((100, 1))
y = tf.random.uniform((100, 1))
z = tf.random.uniform((100, 1))

xyz = tf.concat([x, y, z], 1)

horsepower_normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(input_shape=(3,), axis=-1)
horsepower_normalizer.adapt(xyz)

horsepower_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    horsepower_normalizer,
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)
])

horsepower_model(xyz)
```

Output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(100, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.17135675],
       [-0.48248804],
       [-2.2847023 ],
       [-0.05702276],
       [ 2.9332483 ],
       [ 0.64826846],
       [-2.1490448 ],
       [-1.1697797 ],
       [-0.01030668],
            ...
       [-1.880199  ],
       [ 1.2854142 ],
       [-0.5471661 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: thanks for this but you could fits the layer prior to the model's fit to the data. I want the "adapt" taking place during the fit (aka inside the model - see https://keras.io/guides/preprocessing_layers/). sorry if this was not clear ...

Comment: @cs0815, welcome. Here I use `adapt` too. and ftt the layer prior to the model's fit.

Comment: could you please be so kind and adapt it to "inside model adapt" aka during training?

Comment: @cs0815, Can you write the model that you want?

Comment: thanks - I added some basic code (don't laugh!) see PS - hope this makes sense ...

Comment: @cs0815, No, I'm an egg and I'm not professional too. Ok, where do you want set `adapt` set on the model?

Comment: My understanding is that the model learns it during training and thus stores the means and variances as model parameters. This what I would like to happend but I am not sure if one would set an explicit adapt?

Comment: @cs0815, No, we need to set `adapt` outside of model.fit(). because we want to normalize data before training and this normalization doesn't need to learn and change.

Comment: @cs0815, read [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/using-normalization-layers-to-improve-deep-learning-models/) maybe help you and you can read an example when we need `normalization` [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe) and don't make mistake and think this layer like `BatchNormalization`. `BatchNormalization` apply on nouron of layer but this `Normalization` apply on data.

Comment: Thanks. I pretty much understand the need for normalisation - used it many times also for statiscal models and other transformations. The appeal for me is, that the model can take raw data and the model itself takes care of the normalsiation. So if adpat runs with training data the training data's mean and var is baked into the model?

Comment: @cs0815, `normalize` layer `adapt` on data before training and in training on each epoch first normalize data like adapted before then pass to other layer for training. yes mean and var back to model and use for training.

Comment: so I think you code already does the job then as far as I understand. this trained/deployed model could predict given raw data?

Comment: @cs0815, I need to see an example of your data. Please ask a new question and explain what you want. I or others can see and help you.